# Single Task vs List<Task> in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming

I'm creating a simply port scanner in C#, which is supposed to scan for open ports given an IP range. I'm using `async/await` and `Task` in most part of the code as can be seen below:

```
internal class PortScanner
{
    private IPAddress host;
    private int startPort;
    private int endPort;

    private const int PORT_MIN_VALUE = 1;
    private const int PORT_MAX_VALUE = 65535;

    public PortScanner(IPAddress host, int portStart, int portStop)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.startPort = portStart;
        this.endPort = portStop;
    }

    public PortScanner(IPAddress host)
        : this(host, PORT_MIN_VALUE, PORT_MIN_VALUE)
    {
    }

    private async Task<bool> IsPortOpen(int port)
    {
        Socket socket = null;

        try
        {
            // make a TCP based socket
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // connect
            await Task.Run(() => socket.Connect(this.host, port));

            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionRefused)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket?.Connected ?? false)
            {
                socket?.Disconnect(false);
            }
            socket?.Close();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private async Task CheckPort(int port)
    {
        if (await IsPortOpen(port))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Host: {0} - Port: {1} is open.", this.host.ToString(), port.ToString());
        }
    }

    public async Task Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning for {0}", this.host);
        for (int port = this.startPort; port <= this.endPort; port++)
        {
            await CheckPort(port);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the point is that if in the `Main` function, I use single `Task` like this:

```
try
{
    PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(ipsInRange.Begin, 15, 25);
    var task = ps.Scan();
    task.Wait();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

it works fine, in the sense that I get an output such as (and it takes a few seconds to finish):

```
Scanning for 192.168.1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1 - Port: 21 is open.
Host: 192.168.1.1 - Port: 23 is open.
```

But, when I try to use `List<Task>`, such as this:

```
foreach (var set in setOfIPs)
{
    List<Task> scanTasks = new List<Task>(set.Count());

    foreach (var ip in set)
    {
        scanTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(ip, 15, 25);
            await ps.Scan();
        }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(scanTasks.ToArray());
}
```

What I get as output is simply this (the program also finishes immediately under 1 second):

```
Scanning for 192.168.1.3
Scanning for 192.168.1.2
Scanning for 192.168.1.1
Scanning for 192.168.1.4
Scanning for 192.168.1.5
```

So, it basically doesn't seem to scan each of them separately, as it doesn't print any of the open ports. Any ideas what the problem might be, and how can I call multiple `Task` inside `List<Task>`?

Comment: You should not be deleting and re-posting your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912486/data-parallelism-and-threads-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Servy It's probably cause I narrowed the problem down to something, and made it more explicit.

Comment: If you want to clarify your question you should be editing your question, not deleting it and re-posting it.

Comment: @Servy Okay sorry. It's just once the question gets downvoted, even if you edit it to make it more explicit, it doesn't get much attention.

Comment: "I want to get more attention to my question" isn't a valid reason to delete and re-post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic trap with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The method returns a `Task<T>`, where `T` is the return type of your callback. Your lambda is async, and therefore returns a Task. Put together, you end up with a `Task<Task>`, and you're waiting on the outer task while you should be waiting on the inner task.

Two solutions:

1. The recommended one: use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. That's a general recommendation, you shouldn't ever use `Task.Factory.StartNew` unless you know it's the right solution. `Task.Run` avoids many trap, such as the one you ran into.

   ```
   scanTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
   {
       PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(ip, 15, 25);
       await ps.Scan();
   }));
   ```
2. If you ever have a legitimate reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, then you can use the `.Unwrap()` method on the task to be able to wait on the inner one:

   ```
   scanTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
   {
       PortScanner ps = new PortScanner(ip, 15, 25);
       await ps.Scan();
   }).Unwrap());
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem, and now I understood what the problem is. Is there any particular guideline as when `Task.Factory.StartNew` is appropriate choice?

Comment: @typos Well, long story short: if you want to do something that you can't do with `Task.Run` (so if you ask yourself the question, it means you don't need `Task.Factory.StartNew`). More specifically, it allows you to set a custom task scheduler, as well as some flags on the task (such as `LongRunning` or `PreferFairness`)